# How do I retrieve wsdl element names through soap and php?

Tags: php, soap

I have made a soap client that connects to a WSDL. I am able to run the __getFunctions method and return the WSDL functions. What I need to do is retrieve the 'element name' and the 'element ref' from the WSDL. I am able to view these when I visit the WSDL URL in a browser in xml format but is there a way to get this information through the PHP soap client?

Comment: why not load the WSDL url to a xml parser such as SimpleXML and retrieve from there?